# Making a process bar, showing loaded %?

Tags: jquery

I did some research, and found this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xM6v9/

But I would aswell like to display the percent (%) of the page which have been loaded..

Like showing a text box with "00% percent loaded. please wait". Where "00" should be the percent which is loaded.

How can that be done?

Comment: Have you tried using the search function? This question has been asked so many times... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=loading+bar+jquery

Comment: Please, rename loading bar into progress bar ;)

Comment: It depends on the content you're loading. It could be worth it if you're loading a large file (>10MB) and you should chain it with ajax.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen But would be possible to count percent on ajax?

Comment: It's possible, but I haven't researched it.

Comment: A quick search on google: http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/

Comment: Okay thanks. Else, do you think this would work? pastebin.com/Ky5zZPeA   I will also try out read and understand the source from the link you sentet. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to display the current percentage, and that's why we're using spinning gifs instead of percent based progress bars.

The `load()` function from Jquery only execute ONE callback when the loading process is completed, and this callback is used to remove the spinning gif ...

So you only got 2 information : 0% and 100%

To obtain the exact loading percentage, you'll need to use a second script and call it every 2 sec (for exemple) to update the percentage, but this is useless unless you're doing heavy server-sided operation ...

There is actually no better way.

Comment: yes it will work, you will actually see the progress of the transfer file per file

Answer (score 0):

window.load and document.ready events happen after the page DOM has loaded. If you want to this, you could look into loading sections of the page with [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and then incrementing your percent based on how many sections you are loading. There is no "out of the box" way of doing this.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So by seperating my page into 10 sections, and each section is then 10 percent.

I am gonna do that. But do you think it might work this way: http://pastebin.com/Ky5zZPeA

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/egekaj/1/edit What I created is just a simulation with bar animation, but it animates after each image is loaded.

```
var images = [
'1.jpg',
'2.jpg',
'3.jpg'
];

var imagesN = images.length;

var i = 0;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = (function(){
    for ( i = 0; i < imagesN; ++i ){
        $('#gallery').append('<img src="'+images[i]+'">');   
    }
})(i); 

var c = 0;
$("#gallery img").load(function(i){
    c++;
    var status = c*(100/imagesN)+'%';
    $("#load_status").html( parseInt(status, 10) ); 
    $('#loader').stop().animate({width: status},300);
    if (c === imagesN){
        $("#gallery").fadeIn(700);
        $('#load_status, #loading_bar').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But this insert the images into the html, well, and that would take ages for me to do since that I am having over 1000 images in one page.. But gonna keep this in mind for last solution :) Thanks a ton.

Comment: @MarkoLivendo well, just remove the part that inserts the images. And just for you to know that script as-is will break if image-load failure. Make your steps into improvements.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a ton. I will try this out. And read it for better understanding.